# Prove (informally) every Cauchy sequence is a convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, cauchy-sequences

Since Cauchy sequence meets $|a_{n}-a_{m}|<\epsilon$ for arbitrary numbers $n, m > n_{0}$, **doesn't just picking up some $w>n_{0}$ qualifies as a (informal) proof**? Fixing $b=a_{w}$, and modify the above inequality to $|a_{n}-b|<\epsilon$ makes sense to me.

Comment: So the limit of every Cauchy sequence is a term in that sequence?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Is it wrong?

Comment: Yes it is wrong, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your argument is that you didn't consider dependancy of $n_0$ on $\epsilon$. As $\epsilon$ changes, $n_0$ also changes($n_0$ depends on $\epsilon$). Thus for a different $\epsilon$, the term $b=a_w$ might be invalid to get $|a_n-b| \lt \epsilon$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$n_0$ depends on $ \epsilon$ ! So your $b$ depends on $ \epsilon$ ! With your $b$ you can not garantee that for $ \epsilon/2$ there is $n_1$ such that

$|a_{n}-b|<\epsilon/2$ for all $n >n_1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped a lot.